# Call other scenarios in same karate file, only by tag?

Tags: karate

Hi we have scenarios that calls other scenario in same feature file

`* call read('ShopCheckoutTest.feature@name=payment')`

but sometimes developer renames the test and don't work

can we call scenario in same file? for example:

`* call read('@name=payment')`

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

No, but this is a nice feature request so we've created this issue here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1499

It should be available in 1.2.0